# Error in finding a integers factor by a method

Tags: java, eclipse

My program seems to work with numbers '25, 223, and 11" but i have no idea why it stops when i enter the numbers 10 or 100. Any ideas? Any help on this matter will be greatly appreciated-thank you in advance.

*****Source Code*****

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class hw_5 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner inputReader = new Scanner(System.in);

    int num;
    boolean primeTest;

    System.out.print("Enter an integer value: ");
    num = inputReader.nextInt();

    if(num != -1) {
        primeTest = calcPrime(num);
        if(!primeTest) {

            System.out.println(num+" is not prime.");
            printFactors(num);
        }
    }

}


public static boolean calcPrime(int num) {

    for(int i = 2; i < num; i++) {

        if(num % i == 0)
            return true;    // If number is divisible by any number, return true.
    }

    return false;     // If loop exits (means, number was not divisible by any number), return false.
} 

public static void printFactors(int num) {

    int nFactors = 0;

    for(int i = 2; i < num; i++) {

        if(num % i == 0) {

            System.out.println(num+" is divisible by "+i); 
            nFactors++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(num+" has "+nFactors+" factors");
}

}
```

Comment: You should always use a debugger to look for logical errors like these. `job` is java's debugger located in the `bin` directory in your $JAVA_HOME

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;



public class Test {

public static boolean calcPrime(int num) {

    for(int i = 2; i < num; i++) {

        if(num % i == 0)
            return false;    // If number is divisible by any number, return false.
    }

    return true;     // If loop exits (means, number was not divisible by any number), return true.
}  



public static void printFactors(int num) {

    int nFactors = 0;

    for(int i = 2; i < num; i++) {

        if(num % i == 0) {

            System.out.println(num+" is divisible by "+i); 
            nFactors++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(num+" has "+nFactors+" factors");
}  


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner inputReader = new Scanner(System.in);

    int num = 0;
    boolean primeTest = false;

    while(true) {

        System.out.print("Enter an integer value: ");
        num = inputReader.nextInt();

        if(num == -1)
            break;

        primeTest = calcPrime(num);

        if(primeTest)
            System.out.println(num+" is prime.");
        else {

            System.out.println(num+" is not prime.");
            printFactors(num);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This is close! But when i paste this and change it to boolean, the program just stops when i enter the integer 100. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Actually when i paste these methods over the one i have- the program doesn't work at all :/ it just ends after i input an integer

Comment: I have edited the answer. Please have a look. make the methods `static` and change the `if` condition in the main().

Comment: I have done this and still nothing. I enter 100 and it just stops and when i entered 87 it also stopped- thank you for continuing to help

Comment: Also- i entered 7 and it said it wasn't prime and yet had 0 factors which should mean it IS prime

Comment: Did you write a `!` in your `if` condition? Coz the function works fine for me.

Comment: yeah i did an no luck, ill edit my source code so you can see what it is now

Comment: I'll write the whole class for you. have a look at my answer.

Comment: This has helped me so much! I'm not exactly sure where my mistake was but thank you for you help!

Comment: One more thing, if i may ask, is there a way i could make this loop until the user inputs the number -1?

Comment: put the whole main() methods body in a while loop and check unless num = -1

Comment: I did that as a test before i posted this and it all just kept looping and went crazy lol. I said (while num != -1)

Comment: you did it in an `if` block. i am talking about a `while` loop

Comment: Oh, sorry not talking the code i have posted- i actually added the while loop to your code but it still is doing a continuous loop 0.0

Comment: Oh i see now, i need to put the scanner into the loop so that it'll keep asking. But I'm not exactly sure how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Your prime test is wrong :

```
public static int calcPrime(int number) {
    int primer = number % 2;

    return primer;

}
```

It just tests if the number is odd.

Comment: Oh i see, any suggestions on fixing this method? Thank you

Comment: @user3681591 Use the same logic you use in `calcFactors`, to test if the number n is divisable by any of 2,3,...,sqrt(n).

Answer (score 0):

Below method returns true if it is a prime number ,

```
   boolean isPrime(int n) {
        //check if n is a multiple of 2
        if (n%2==0) return false;
        //if not, then just check the odds
        for(int i=3;i*i<=n;i+=2) {
            if(n%i==0)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

You could add the numbers to the `list` and get the their values on iterating back

Comment: would it be a problem if you start count of i from 2 rather than having a separate if condition above the loop?